# A realistic and usable (VS2010) MVC2 project template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, project-template

The default MVC2 web project template which VS2010 creates when you select "ASP.NET MVC2 Web Application" is quite a nice start... but nowhere near a realistic app framework.
E.G.: user accounts without such features as

- password recover
- easily customizabile (and maybe multilingual) error messages
- an interface to manage users, such a
  searcheable user list, user edit and 
  so on which an admin can use

and these are just the beginning of the usual, mandatory basic features a web site of any size may use.

Searching through the online projects templates doesn't seem to help, ehiter.
Are there any project template sites or else that you are aware of, that gives such features?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at [S#arp Architecture](http://sharparchitecture.codeplex.com/) and [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/).

Comment: these are fine frameworks, and I'll accept this answer, even if they are not exactely what I was looking for.
Anyway, if anyone wants to contribute with other links, please do it.